# Why do I get constraints errors when pushing view controller from within a completion block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, block

I have two methods to register in the app - the first one is a manual form and the second one uses facebook data.

For the second option, I am using a callback from the Facebook API to fetch their data, and when the process completes I push to the next view controller.

The difference is that, in the case where I push the new viewcontroller from within the completion block I get all sorts of constraints warnings, while the view controller that is pushed directly doesn't cause any warnings.

To test, I tried pushing the VC from within a completion block in UIView animation as well, causing the same issues.

This code causes constraints errors and a jumbled next page:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
VCName *enroll = [[VCName alloc]initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:enroll animated:YES];

}];
```

This code displays the next screen perfectly:

```
VCName *enroll = [[VCName alloc]initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:enroll animated:YES];
```

**Update**
The layout works fine if I run `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` on the target view controller of the transition. Not sure why this is necessary only when the VC is pushed from a block though.

Comment: Is that code executing on the main thread? Verify just to be sure: [NSThread isMainThread] and break on YES.

Comment: I'm not sure of the details, would be surprised if the completion block for a `UIView` animation was executed on a background thread. It would be super inconvenient on Apple's part.

Comment: @cdstamper interestingly, if I forced it to happen on the main thread with dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()... they both returned jumbled target VC's - seems to be anything that is being queued up. Anyway I found a solution to my problem, just wish I knew why.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Yep, it is executed on the main thread

Comment: However, I also first thought "UI update on background thread!" when I first read the question title.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch, but... self.navigationController doesn't have a fixed value -- it's a method call which searches up the hierarchy for the closest navigationController. Maybe that process doesn't work in the context in which the block is executed?

Try creating a variable outside the block (I think it needs to have the __block prefix), setting it to the result of self.navigationController, and then using that inside the block. That way, you precisely determine the reference being captured by the block.

Comment: Good hunch - I hadn't considered that, still didn't solve it for me though. I found a fix (see update), but I still have no clue why this has to be done only for callbacks! :)